# Selectively Highlight lines in source code block

Tags: org-mode, org-export, org-babel

I use emacs org-mode and find feature of source code blocks extremely useful. However, If I want to say highlight a couple of lines in my source code block, is it possible to achieve?
e.g.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC java
int i = 0;
m() //this is new call
#+END_SRC
```

Here when I export my org-mode to HTML or some other format, I want

```
m() //this is new call
```

to stand out. The intention is convey your message as clearly as possible.

Comment: Just for completeness, you forgot to add the programming language

Answer (score 1):

One option for highlighting (not specific to org-mode) would be the built in `hi-lock` commands. You can use commands interactively to highlight a line or phrase matching a pattern, then save those patterns in the file for future use.

For example:

- `M-s h l this is a new call` to highlight the line
- `M-s h w` to write the current hi-lock patterns to the file

If you close and then re-open the file, you can run `M-x hi-lock-mode` and have the option to read the patterns from the file and re-apply them. If you always want this you can set up an org-mode hook to enable hi-lock.

See [Highlight Interactively](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Highlight-Interactively.html#Highlight-Interactively) in the Emacs manual for details.

Comment: I am not sure if I do an org-export, it will display the highlighting there also.

Comment: Ah - no, this approach is only useful in Emacs. If you need to export the highlight then you will need some org-specific approach, not sure what is possible there.